# Why is my Google Sheets function so slow?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I like the form of function `IFNA( expression, value_if_NA )` to check for conditions without having to evaluate twice.

So, I thought I would write the function that I thought was missing, `IFZERO( expression, value_if_zero )`. My function works, but it seems to be especially slow and sometimes deadlocks (shows "Loading..." in a small percentage of cells).

```
function IFZERO( expression, valueIfZero )
{
  var result = eval( expression );
  if ( result === 0 )
    return valueIfZero;
  return result;
}
```

My usage is in a column of cells with this type of formula:

```
=IFZERO( E70 - SUMIF( A:A, A70, G:G ), "" )
```

Result:
Cell shows "Loading..." and takes about 500ms to execute one cell.

There are only about 80 rows in my sheet, and although the values in A, G, etc. are pulled from `FILTER()` results from other sheets, the equivalent (but less pretty)

```
=IF( E70 - SUMIF( A:A, A70, G:G ) = 0, "", E70 - SUMIF( A:A, A70, G:G ) )
```

returns instantaneously.

My question is: Did I miss some kind of optimization in my JavaScript function? I wonder if there is an event based way to do the same thing, without having to `eval()` in the JavaScript layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

I think that in your custom function, `expression` given by `=IFZERO( E70 - SUMIF( A:A, A70, G:G ), "" )` has already been calculated. So you can modify as follows.

```
function IFZERO(result, valueIfZero) {
  return result === 0 ? valueIfZero : result
}
```

- By this modification, `eval()` is not required to be used.
- Also you can use this modified script as `=IFZERO( E70 - SUMIF( A:A, A70, G:G ), "" )`.

Comment: Thank you, I think Modified Script 1 is an excellent solution. I did not think clearly about processing order. I will try this.

Comment: @Douglas Held Thank you for replying. `result === 0 ? valueIfZero : result` is the ternary operator. In this case, it can also write as `if (result === 0) {return valueIfZero} else {return result}`. The document is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: If you delete everything from Modified Script 2, then I will mark your answer as "correct". Thank you.

Comment: @Douglas Held Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to mask the zero, you can use `=TEXT()`

```
=TEXT([FORMULA TO EVALUATE], "0;0;;@")
```

But this changes the result from number to string type. You should multiply by 1 `*1`, if you want to use the  result in other numeric calculations.

- [=TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)
- [Number pattern](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns)